# Regex to remove punctuation from tokenized text

Tags: regex

I'm trying to remove punctuation from tokenized text using regular expressions.  Can anyone explain the following behaviour:

```
$ STRING='hey , you ! what " are you doing ? say ... ," what '
$ echo $STRING | sed -r 's/ [^[:alnum:][:space:]-]+ / /g;'
hey you what are you doing say ," what
$ echo $STRING | sed -r 's/ [[:punct:]]+ / /g;'
hey you what are you doing say ," what
$ echo $STRING | perl -pe 's/ [^[:alnum:][:space:]-]+ / /g;'
hey you what are you doing say ," what
$ echo $STRING | perl -pe 's/ [[:punct:]]+ / /g;'
hey you what are you doing say ," what
```

The `,"` token is preserved in the output, which I don't want.  It's possible to match this token with:

```
$ echo $STRING | perl -pe 's/ [",]+ / /g;'
hey you ! what are you doing ? say ... what
```

Comment: What's your question and what explaination do you want?

Comment: Or what is your expected output?

Comment: Matches in a global regex search cannot overlap. So if your regex is `/_[[:punct:]]+_/` and your string is `_..._,"`, it first matches `_..._` and then looks for the next match in the remaining string `,"_`. This lacks the required leading `_` and so won't match.

Comment: One solution would be to use a lookaround: `/(?<![^ ])[[:punct:]]+ /`.

Comment: Just use the chainsaw: `echo $STRING | perl -pe 's/\s*(?:\p{P}+\s*)++/ /g;'` :-)

Comment: @ConnorSmith that's the explanation, thanks!  I can't count the number of times I've been bitten by overlapping matches before.  The lookaround fixes my problem.

Comment: @ConnorSmith Please make that an answer!